# Porting .NET library to .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

So I have a library that targets .NET 4.6.1 and I am trying to figure out what would be the correct way to port it so it can be used by projects targeting .NET Core while still being able to be use it in .NET 4.6.1.

The library has dependencies on Win Forms and System.Windows; as I understand, this functionality will be only available in .NET Core 3?
And also as I understand I will need to port it to .NET Standard 2.1?

Apart from clearing out up .NET Standard version I will need to target I am wondering if its possible to have this same library to have some code that will not be supported on all platforms like Native Win 32 APIs?

Comment: Winforms and/or WPF will never be part of .NETStandard.  They are not standard.

Comment: The [Portability analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) could help you understanding the compatibility level of your project

Comment: .NET Core 3 supports much of WinForms (but .NET Standard does and will not) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms

Comment: Ok so based on what you say i understand that 1) I will need to create a separate library that will have any WPF/Winforms stuff and have it target multiple frameworks? 2) Have second library that targets .NET Standard and work on any framework?

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20